# php how to echo a session name in echo and use it i as html code

Tags: php, html, session

I have a php code in a div but I want the username show after the user has logged in but how could I echo a session inside an echo?

```
<?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
            {
                echo '<ul class="nav" action="Login.html" method="post">
                    <li class="loginbtn"><a href="#">echo '$_SESSION['username'];'</a></li>
                    <li class="loginbtn"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>';
                    }
```

Comment: if the session array contains value, then that should work (Edit: see the latter part of my comment). If not, assign value to it and start the session. Btw, you have a parse error here, which would throw `unexpected T_ECHO`.

Comment: oic, thanks bro the problem solved !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
echo '<ul class="nav" action="Login.html" method="post">
                <li class="loginbtn"><a href="#">'.$_SESSION['username'].'</a></li>
                <li class="loginbtn"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>';
```

You don't need to call `echo` again and you don't need a semicolon